# Concatenating video files

Tags: windows

I’m on Windows 10.
My nephew emailed me several times - a large video file broken up into smaller pieces.  Is there a fairly easy way to string them back together so I can reconstruct the original file?

Here’s what I got:
Small files - File1, File2, File3…

I want:
Large file – File1 + File2 + File3…

Thanks,

jb

Comment: How did he split the large file? Can every small file be played separately without issues? What are the names (and extensions) of the files? Please [edit] the question and add information.

Comment: Are the files individual video files (e.g. 30 second snippets) that you need to splice back together... or do you have file "fragments" that are part of a compressed ("zip", "tar",...) file that you need to re-assemble into a single file?

Comment: they are each an individual snippet that I can view separately

Comment: I'm not really sure how he split up the *.MOV files (7 in all).  I can play each of them individually no problem.  I'd just like to parse them back into its original length.  I tried using the TYPE and COPY commands - but no luck.